# Exist a diference in use django-admin.py or manage.py

Tags: python, django

I'm learning something about Django.In some tutorials that i've read is used **django-admin.py** for execute commands like " syncdb, startapp and startproject", in the others tutorials is used **manage.py**, So exist any important diference between use **django-admin.py** or **manage.py** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manage.py is a file that excists in a project environment and is created after starting a project. It's purpose is to control project commands. Django-admin.py is a script to start a project ( you can put it anyhwhere, or shortcut it via .bash or .profile )

Answer (score 6):

See: [django-admin.py and manage.py in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)

*manage.py* is a wrapper around *django-admin.py* automatically created in each Django project which puts your project's package on **sys.path** and sets the **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** environment variable so that it points to your project's settings.py file.

So, I think is more comfortable to use manage.py when you're working on a Django project.

Answer (score 1):

manage.py is django-admin fitted in your project: it uses settings.py in your project dir